# How to sort a list alphabetically in reverse but numbers first

Tags: python, sorting

I'm coding a simple blackjack program they way I coded I need "A" to be sorted to the end of the list so it must be reversed alphabetically and all the numbers should be checked before it

revelant part of the code:

```
oyuncukart = []
eroskart = []
oyuncuToplam = 0
erosToplam = 0

def Donustur(El,oyuncuTop):
    aTane = El.count("A")
    for kart in El:
        if "2" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 2
        if "3" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 3
        if "4" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 4
        if "5" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 5
        if "6" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 6
        if "7" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 7
        if "8" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 8
        if "9" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 9
        if "10" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 10
        if "J" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 10
        if "Q" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 10
        if "K" == kart:
            oyuncuTop += 10
        if "A" == kart and aTane == 1 and oyuncuTop <= 10:
            oyuncuTop += 11
        elif "A" == kart and aTane == 1 and oyuncuTop > 10:
            oyuncuTop += 1
        elif "A" == kart and aTane > 1  and oyuncuTop < 10:
            oyuncuTop += 11
        elif "A" == kart and aTane > 1 and oyuncuTop >= 10:
            oyuncuTop += 1

    return oyuncuTop

kartlar = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"]


oyuncukart.append(random.choice(kartlar))
oyuncukart.append(random.choice(kartlar))
oyuncukart.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: Please show an example of the expected output.

Comment: If the drawn cards are A and K expect the list to be sorted as ```oyuncukart = ["K","A"]```
If the drawn cards are 2 and A ```oyuncukart = ["2","A"]``` 
otherwise my if statements won't work properly. other cards don't matter much but A must be at the end of the list no matter what

Comment: I suggest to always code in English. Your variable names make zero sense to me.

Comment: sorry for that I wasn't expecting to require any help my bad on that part

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to sort numerically *or* alphabetically (reversed or not); you want the Very Special sort order `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,J,Q,K,A`.

You can apply a custom order to `sort` inside the command itself:

```
oyuncukart.sort(key=["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"].index)
```

and this might produce (with more draws than 2 -- but it's only about the *sort* order so that doesn't matter) a sequence such as this:

```
['2', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'A']
```

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a different way, with a function that returns the value of the card that can be used as a `key` argument to `sorted()`. That would give us the following:

**Code:**

```
face_cards = {'J': 11,
              'Q': 12,
              'K': 13,
              'A': 14}

def card_val(card):
    try:
        return int(card)
    except ValueError:
        return face_cards[card]

kartlar = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"]

sorted_kartlar = sorted(kartlar, key=card_val)
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> import random
>>> kartlar = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"]
>>> random.shuffle(kartlar)
>>> kartlar
['6', '4', '10', 'J', '2', 'A', 'K', '8', '3', '5', 'Q', '9', '7']
>>> sorted(kartlar, key=card_val)
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
```

Comment: in hindsight it makes more sense to do it this way but there is much more to the code than I shared and it would interfere with it too much but I REALLY appreaciate your suggestion